# How to disable all hardware keys programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-hardware

I am developing Android application with lock functionality. please suggest me how to disable all the hard keys programmatically. here I am using below code to disable back button. I want like this functionality for all hard keys like home,search,camera, shortcut keys
here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
        Log.d("KeyPress", "search");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution to this Bro ?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your onKey method to this :

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return true;
}
```

When you return true from onKey method, it means that you have handled the key press yourself and prevents the OS from taking the default action.
In you code, you are only handling the search button, but when you return true for all cases, it will block all buttons.

P.S this might not work for soft buttons. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html)

Comment: I need the same thing for ICS devices also. This is not worked in Ics device.

Comment: Add public boolean onKeyDown(int i, KeyEvent event) {return true;} in your activity instead of any view.

Comment: why would you want to disable home button ? its not possible to prevent home button from taking default action.

Comment: Kiran is correct. you cannot disable the home button...user always must have a way to exit an app.

Answer (score 0):

Override `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` func, return them `true`, it means you handle press action yourself. In onKeyUp, you can implement more logic for each key press action if you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this, it may solve your problem:

```
@Override

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
            System.out.println("KEYCODE_HOME");
            return true;
        }
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            System.out.println("KEYCODE_BACK");
            return true;
        }
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)) {
            System.out.println("KEYCODE_MENU");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```