# How to reduce the time delay between Activity Pause and Re-Start(by a Service)?

Tags: android

I am implementing an activity to be on top always ( generally implementing a lock screen),
The Algorithm is simple as :

1. Start Activity
2. Disable All Hardware buttons, disable backpress,camera lock, volume buttons etc.
3. Whenever activity is paused call a service to check and restart the activity.

Refer to these answers for the logic: [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658567/how-to-disable-all-hardware-keys-programatically-in-android.), [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262157/how-to-check-if-my-activity-is-the-current-activity-running-in-the-screen)
There is a 6-7 seconds delay whenever the Activity is paused, and is restarted by the Service. How may I reduce this time delay between the pause and restart of my Activity.

On Pause and On Resume Code:

```
protected void onPause() {
    isFront = false;
    Intent lockHelper = new Intent( this, LockHelper.class);
    startService( lockHelper );
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)
        return true;
    else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
        return true;
    else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
        return true;
    else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
        return true;
    else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)
        return true;
    else 
        return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
        return true;
    else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)
        return true;
    else 
        return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    isFront = true;
    Intent lockHelper = new Intent( this, LockHelper.class);
    startService( lockHelper );
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

Service is:

```
public class LockHelper extends Service {
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    if(Locker.isFront == false){
        Intent locker = new Intent( this, Locker.class);
        locker.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity( locker );
        stopSelf();
    }
}

public LockHelper() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
}
```

Comment: I suggest you do a more detailed timestamp debugging, is the `6-7 seconds` calculated based on your instinct? You may log a message on Activity.onPause(), Service.onStart(), Activity.onCreate() and Activity.onResume(). This way you know which part is taking a lot of time based on Log timestamp. And take away stopSelf, place your codes on onStartCommand instead, recreation of service may takes significant amount of time, and I believe that is where your delay happens.

Comment: @ChorWaiChun no not on basis of instinct actually the Activity has a clock in its layout, i check the time by the clock, i.e the number of second for which the Activity is hidden.

Comment: well then I'd suggest you make a little changes on your service based on my previous comments.

Comment: @RachitMishra I am facing same issue. Did you get the solution?

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani nah! i went with different approach now.

Comment: @RachitMishra ok Thanks ! Can you share what was the approached you followed?

Comment: Yea! so if you are now making a lock service, you should explore accessibility service in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your onPause, onStop and onDestroy should execute as fast as possible. That is to say, don't block these methods by putting a lot of code here. But again, it depends on what you are doing here. If those things are really important, I am not sure how you can reduce the time delay.

Comment: The code in these methods simple start a service, which check if the Activity is in background, and restarts the Activity.

Comment: I agree with @Kumar Bibek, its your code efficiency in your onPause, onStop and onDestroy will matter. Use disable code only to those, which are really neccessary.

Comment: I get exactly 6 seconds delay. :|

Answer (score 0):

> "is how may I reduce this time delay between the pause and restart of my Activity."

Did you measure the time cost happened this two interval?

Basically, two type of task: one is system task and your app task.

`adb logcat -b system -v threadtime` should print out all the system bahvoir related to Activity/Service start/stop, along with the timestamp.

You should/could reduce the time spend on your app as much as possible but there is no way to reduce the time cost of system behavior.